# How to disable Ajax-upload button?

Tags: jquery, ajax-upload

I'm trying to use this plugin http://valums.com/ajax-upload/.
I added a file-limit, I want to disable the upload button (not hide, just disable).
E.g.

```
if(filesNumber>=limit)
{
    //Disable the "Upload a file" button    
}
```

So, if the user will try to upload another file, he should see a message that the limit is exceeded.
Can you look at this plugin and help me?

The button is not a form button, it is a div with css.

```
var btnUpload=$('#<?=$filesManagerCode?>upload');
        new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
            action: '<?=$boxLink?>actionMode<?=LDTR?>addfile',
            name: 'uploadFile[FilePath]',
            onSubmit: function(file, ext){
                btnUpload.attr('oldContent', btnUpload.html());
                btnUpload.html('<img src="'+jsloader.src+'"/>');
            },
            onComplete: function(file, response, temp){
                btnUpload.html(btnUpload.attr('oldContent'));
                $("#<?=$filesManagerCode?>files").load('<?=$boxLink?>', setFilesLimit(<?=$params['filesLimit']?>));
            }
        });


<div id="<?=$filesManagerCode?>upload" class="uploadButton"><span>Upload file</span> <span id="<?=$filesManagerCode?>uploadLimit"></span></div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var btnUpload=$('#<?=$filesManagerCode?>upload');
           if(filesNumber>=limit)
{
    //Disable the "Upload a file" button or Do nothing:
       alert("You have reached the upload limit.");
}
else
{
            new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
                action: '<?=$boxLink?>actionMode<?=LDTR?>addfile',
                name: 'uploadFile[FilePath]',
                onSubmit: function(file, ext){
                    btnUpload.attr('oldContent', btnUpload.html());
                    btnUpload.html('<img src="'+jsloader.src+'"/>');
                },
                onComplete: function(file, response, temp){
                    btnUpload.html(btnUpload.attr('oldContent'));
                    $("#<?=$filesManagerCode?>files").load('<?=$boxLink?>', setFilesLimit(<?=$params['filesLimit']?>));

            });
}
```

Comment: No, it is not a form button, it is a <div> with css. I should change  the css class ( I can do this ) and I should to disable the browsing window, when it is clicked.

Comment: @Denis, so your upload button isn't actually a button, it's a div? Can you post the click function for that button then? I can modify it for you.

Comment: Thanks, I added it. See my first post.

Comment: Is your idea to run the AjaxUploader just in case the limit is not exceeded? I wanted to run it always, but your idea is also good. Thanks. I looked at this plugin and seen that there is a way to disable the uploader, but I can't do this...

Comment: @Denis, I updated my answer. What do you mean by always run the ajax uploader?

Comment: Yes, I will use this way. Thanks.