# Disable upload button after uploading image http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this, valums ajax fileupload: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ ,  It is working fine for  me. I want to disable the upload button as I upload an image and want add 2 more buttons beside it "Delete" and "View". How would I do this using existing JS file.

Comment: showing some of your code would help.. dont you think so..?

Comment: something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122602/how-to-disable-ajax-upload-button

Comment: Hey Sudhir, definitely I'll post like this next time. Thanks a lot guiding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it as below

```
$.ajax({
....
....
....
success:function(resposne){
  // do something 
  $('#upload').attr("disabled", true);
  $('#upload').parent().append('<input type="button" value="delete" id="delete"/>
                                 <input type="view" value="click" id="view"/>');
    }    
});
```

then for handling delete and view button click, since these are `dynamically` added element you have to `delegate` `event` `handler` using `on`. The `normal` `click` `handler` will not work on `dynamically` added elements.

```
$('body').on("click","#delete",function(){
// do the delete operation
});

$('body').on("click","#view",function(){
// do the view operation
});
```

Answer (score 0):

without any code all we can do is guess, but assuming there are 2 elements, a button with id='upload-button' that is a child of an element with id='upload-button-container' you could do something like the following:

```
$("#upload-button").hide();
$("#upload-button-container").append($("<button type='button'>Delete</button><button type='button'>View</button>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if your upload button has the id "upload_button"
and the two buttons you want to add are already there, but hidden. (and with the class "hidden_btn")

with jquery, you can do this:

```
$("#upload_button").attr("disabled","disabled")
$(".hidden_btn").show()
```